# Split function problems with white spaces

Tags: java, split

I want to separate a string with special characters for example:

```
String s = ",?hello=glu()Stop/<><$#!gluglufazoperu";
```

I use the split function to obtain the normal characters:

```
hello
glu
Stop
gluglufazoperu
```

I have a problem, when I use the split it puts whitespace in the begining of the string array, anyone knows how to remove it?

Here is my code example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = ",?hello=glu()Stop/<><$#!gluglufazoperu";
        String f[] = s.split("[^\\w \\s]+");
        int i= 0;

        while(i < f.length){
            System.out.println(f[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:
    (whitespace)
    hello
    glu
    Stop
    gluglufazoperu

Comment: You can first replace special characters with a single space, trim the result and then split. However you will still need to handle the corner case of empty string.

Comment: your code's running fine on my end

Comment: Your code is also running fine here.

Comment: You could remove the first and last elements of the returned array or just check with an if statement if it's a white-space then don't print...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a whitespace because the first split between ',' and '?' returns an empty string "".
With your while loop you print System.out.println(""), and that is an empty line.

When you only want to print the not empty strings you should replace your System.out.println with

```
if(!"".equals(f[i])){
System.out.println(f[i]);
}
```

And (beside your question) a little tip, take a look at this tutorial.

[oracle for loop tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: `!"".equals(f[i])` could be replaced with [`!f[i].isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--)

Comment: correct! tnx for the addition. i prefer "".equals because then u can't get a null pointer, but that is only a matter of taste.

Comment: it works, but can you tell me what does "" means? what are you comparing?

Comment: "" means an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Not whitespace but empty string as ",?" is a separator too. This could happen at the end too.

You might simple skip an empty string.
You might remove those from the array, which is costly, as it makes a copy.

```
if (f.length > 1) {
    if (f[0].isEnpty()) {
        f = Arrays.copyOfRange(f, 1, f.length);
    }
    if (f.length > 1) {
        if (f[f.length - 1].isEnpty()) {
            f = Arrays.copyOfRange(f, 0, f.length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Remarks:

- `String[] f = ...` is more conventional in java.
- `\\s`  already captures the space, and do you really want to keep spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace the longest prefix the string matching your regular expression with the empty string before splitting:

```
final String regex = "[^\\w \\s]+";
String f[] = s.replaceAll("^"+regex, "")
              .split(regex);
```